# MvvmLight toolkit installer 4.0.23.1.msi, no VS2010 templates installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am running the GalaSoft MvvmLight Toolkit MSI installer (GalaSoft.MvvmLight.4.0.23.1.msi) but I do not get any templates or snippets installed.

Need this asap, any quick help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest version (4.0.23.2). Also, if that does not seem to work you can install the snippets and the templates manually from the latest mvvm light source code (look on the left under the Snippets and Templates folders): http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b9bb3f49bb0e

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the latest version 4.1 and there is no template. After the install it says i must install the vsix extension file but i am not to sure where that exists, it does not exist as an extension in the extension library . I can add it by adding the nuget package on a blank win 8 store app but its kinda odd watching all the tutorials and they just create the thing by adding the template. Dont think it makes much different but ...